# Resque Gem - I cannot get the proper queue data

Tags: resque, rails-activejob

Why I cannot get all the queues data, using `Resque.queues`
The result in json was:

```
{
  data: [
    "active_calls"
  ]
}
```

Only the name in:

```
class ActiveCallsJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :active_calls << (this name)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `queue_as` line will be executed only once when the code will be parsed. But there's another solution for your issue: you can pass a block to `queue_as`. See here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#queues